# nobara-sync cli command does not consider -y flag answer to the question asked

Tags: fedora, upgrade

In Nobara Linux, you can run `nobara-sync cli` to update your system from the command line. At some point during the update process, questions like these come to the prompt: `QUESTION: Flatpak has been detected! Would like to update all Flatpaks on your system? [y/n]` or `It's recommended to reboot the system after an update. Do you wish to reboot now?`. If I try to give an answer in advance to this question using a flag like `-y`, that is not considered.

What I want to achieve is to give answers in advance to the questions being asked in the prompt while the command is being executed. Is it possible?